# Kubernetes volumes with gitRepo for specific file

Tags: kubernetes

I know how to mount git repo when I start pod. See:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: server
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mypath
      name: git-volume
  volumes:
  - name: git-volume
    gitRepo:
      repository: "git@somewhere:me/my-git-repository.git"
      revision: "22f1d8406d464b0c0874075539c1f2e96c253775"
```

That's perfect, but it means that I need to clone whole repository. What I need is to obtain "clone" only one file.

```
  - name: git-volume
        gitRepo:
          repository: "git@somewhere:me/my-git-repository.git/some/long/path/to/specific/file/configuration.cfg"
```

Is it possible?

Or can I mount some volume and execute some command in it? Something like:

```
...
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mypath
      name: git-volume
      command: wget htttp://gitrepo/path/to/file/config.conf
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't clone only one file. `gitRepo` executes `git clone` which only allows you to clone the entire repository.

`volumeMounts` doesn't support executing command in it.

Comment: As I was expected. Thanks for reply.

Comment: hi, I'm interested to know wheter you found a solution to your problem. If not, how did you implement your setup?